# How to tell codeception to finish selection from a dropdown list items without clicking any submit button

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, webdriver, codeception

i can select element from a drop down list in codeception but somehow it is not showing as selected in box as i think the select operation is somehow not finished.I donot have any submit button so i tried to move my focus to any other element on the page but still the select box stay empty.Below is my code to select item from a dropdown list.

```
$I->selectOption('//*[@class="ng-scope" and @ng-controller="dataIsland"]/*[local-name()="select"]','partlycloudy');
```

please help.

Answer (score 0):

thanks but i got my answer,below code can help you to select element from drop down list.

```
$I->pressKey('//*[@xpath to the form]/*[local-name()="select"]','element to select',WebDriverKeys::ENTER);
```

thanks !